# Why JavaScript push() method doesn't add comma between array elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to add array elements dynamically using jQuery each() and JavaScript push() methods. When I display array after adding elements using alert(), then there is a comma between each elements but when I display my array elements on webpage using jQuery html() method then there is not comma between and array elements are displayed as a long string. I don't understand why does this happen? So how can I add comma between each array element while displaying them on the page (except comma after the last one)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div_array = new Array();
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper .selected").each(function() {
      div_array.push($(this).children("p").text());
    });
    alert(div_array);
    $("#response").html(div_array);
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.mydiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 5</p>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get Selected Div" />

  <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note, and I'm not 100% sure on this but I feel like it needs to be said: the difference in behavior you are seeing I believe is caused by the fact that the `alert()` method calls `Array.prototype.toString()` to display an array as a readable string. jQuery's `.html` method simply calls the `Array.prototype.join()` method with an empty string as the concatenator, but I honestly haven't looked at jQuery's source for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("#response").html(div_array.join(','));` instead

```js
var div_array = new Array();
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#wrapper .selected").each(function() {
    div_array.push($(this).children("p").text());
  });
  alert(div_array);
  $("#response").html(div_array.join(','));
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.mydiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 5</p>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get Selected Div" />

  <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just join() will do. It uses comma by default.

Comment: yes join() does what I want. But but... my question is still remained unanswered. Why comma in alert() and not in html() ? Any idea?

Comment: Alert prints it as debug value, and debug value of array have comas in between by default, but `array.toString()` does not.

Comment: @Akxe: *"but array.toString() does no"* Um, try this in your console: `[1,2,3].toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to `.join()` the array elements into a string when displaying them on the page. The [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method accepts a string as a parameter to separate each pair of adjacent elements of the array. If no value is passed to `.join()`, the default value is a `,`, so you can use just `.join()`.

So you can use:

```
$("#response").html(div_array.join());
```

resulting in,

```
Item1,Item2,Item3
```

or use a `", "` as the `.join()` parameter to put a comma and space between each element:

```
Item1, Item2, Item3
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div_array = new Array();
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper .selected").each(function() {
      div_array.push($(this).children("p").text());
    });
    $("#response").html(div_array.join(", "));
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.mydiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 5</p>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get Selected Div" />

  <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you remove my jsfiddle link?

Comment: We can create code snippets that run within the question itself. This means we don't worry about the jsFiddle being deleted down the road and the question being incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` calls `toString` on your array which adds the commas. jquery [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function does not do this and instead appends the items in the array as text nodes. i.e. each  string in your array will be appended as a text node to the response div.

If you try using [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) it will print out the array as you see in the alert as this sets the `textContent` of the element to the array (which in turn would call `toString`).

```js
var div_array = new Array();
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#wrapper .selected").each(function() {
    div_array.push($(this).children("p").text());
  });
  alert(div_array);
  $("#response").text(div_array);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.mydiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 5</p>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get Selected Div" />

  <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div_array = new Array();
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper .selected").each(function() {
      div_array.push($(this).children("p").text());
    });
    alert(div_array);
    $("#response").text(div_array);
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.mydiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv selected">
    <p>Div 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Div 5</p>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get Selected Div" />

  <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```